# Importing a matrix in Matlab to Julia

Tags: arrays, matlab, julia, sparse-matrix

I have been given a Matlab file that is supposed to contain some matrices. I'm opening it on Matlab online and it looks like an excel sheet where each cell has a variable of class `double` and is mentioned as `sparse double`. If I try to print this, it gives me a list of coordinates followed by 1. For example:

```
(100,1)   1
(123,132) 1
```

The matrix I am working with can only have 0,1 as elements so I assume all other coordinates are zero. However, I have no idea how to display this as a matrix or somehow import this as an array into Julia. I have no knowledge of Matlab, and I don't even want to work on Matlab since the rest of my program is in Julia anyway.

**EDIT**: As suggested by a comment I am just leaving the code I'm using in order to try to import it. In the Matlab program I have a single variable in "cell" format which is of size 1x10 called `modmat`. Each of these contains 1 `266x266 sparse double` matrix, which I am accessing as `modmat{1}`, `modmat{2}` etc.

Matlab:

```
writematrix(modmat{1},"Mat1.txt")
```

In Julia:

```
> using DelimitedFiles
> M1 = open(readdlm,"Mat1.txt")
```

The output is a `266×1 Matrix{Any}:` variable

Comment: Yes, entries not shown in a Matlab sparse matrix are `0`. To display the full matrix convert to [`full`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) (if the matrix is not too big). Specifically, type `y = full(x)` in the command window, where `x` is the matrix name. To import from Julia, it may be handy to save in Matlab as a text file; use [`writematrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) for that (unless Julia can read `.mat` files directly, I don't know that language)

Comment: This seems to give me a 266x1 array in Julia but the original matrix is a 266x266 matrix. Could you point me to some resources where I can learn how to do this properly?

Comment: I don't know Julia, sorry. Maybe someone who knows the language will help. Have you checked that Matlab reads the saved matrix properly ([`readmatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html))? I recommend you update the question with the code you are using in both languages

Comment: @LuisMendo I have edited the question as you have suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend the [MAT.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/MAT.jl) package to read in `mat` files safely and efficiently. It looks like it can read in sparse matrices too, and even read the whole cell array in one go.

For completeness' sake (and in case you're not able to do the above for some reason), here's how you can read a file containing lines of the format

```
(100,1)   1
(123,132) 1
```

:

```
function readsparsemat(io::IO)
  linere = r"^\((\d+),(\d+)\) # coordinates
             \s+              # some number of spaces
             1$               # 1 at the end of the line
             "x               # extended regex complete

  matches = match.(linere, readlines(io))
  coords = [parse.(Int, (m[1], m[2])) for m in matches]

  sparse(first.(coords), last.(coords), true)
  
end
```

```
julia> readsparsemat(IOBuffer("(10,1)   1
       (12,13) 1
       ")) # test with an IOBuffer
12×13 SparseMatrixCSC{Bool, Int64} with 2 stored entries:
...

julia> open(readsparsemat, "matfilename") #actual usage
```

Comment: Thanks!
I was aware of the MAT.jl package but since I do not have a local installation of Matlab I was unable to use it. Thanks for your alternative method of getting it done.

Comment: I am able to read the `mat` file, but as I have mentioned, the file has a single variable `v` of cell format of size (1x10). Each of these is a `sparse double` matrix. I am able to read the file itself in `Julia` and I have set it to a variable. But can I access each of the 10 components `v{1}`, `v{2}`,. .etc on `Julia` somehow, as an array?

Comment: @newtothis Firstly, can you explain what you mean by "I was aware of the MAT.jl package but since I do not have a local installation of Matlab I was unable to use it"? MAT.jl doesn't need MATLAB to be installed to work, and would be the easiest way to go about it. Have you tried installing it, and if so what issue do you encounter?

Comment: The code in my answer is to handle the " list of coordinates followed by 1" mentioned in your question; if the format in the file is something more complex than that, I'd like to make sure we're not just reinventing some complicated cell array parsing code when it's already available in MAT.jl

Comment: When I originally posted the question, I was under the impression (incorrectly) that I needed a local installation of Matlab in order for `MAT.jl` to work. Hence, I managed to figure out a work around before you posted your answer. However, I need to work with a similar file again, and my method is not efficient.

Comment: I have since installed `MAT.jl` and as I mentioned now, I have been able to read the required `mat` file, but since it is of this complicated format, I would like to know if there is a way to access the individual slices. I checked the `MAT.jl` github page, but that wasn't helpful, and I didn't understand much.

Comment: @newtothis Ah, I understand the issue better now. You should be able to just do `v[1]`, `v[2]`, etc. to get the individual matrices, but if not, can you open that as a separate question so we can get into the details? Specifically, the code with which you're reading the file into a variable, and the type of the variable after you've assigned the result to it.